# How to label PCA points based on sample id in R

Tags: r

I have a PCA Plot made using object "tab":

```
>tab
    sample.id           EV1           EV2
1        G495 -0.0074331465 -3.837111e-02
2          G1 -0.0141980856  6.964191e-02
3         G10 -0.0866563029  2.645573e-02
4        G162 -0.0052063398  5.399684e-02
5        G163 -0.0200554468  2.769749e-02
```

Code for PCA Plot:

```
plot(tab$EV2, tab$EV1, xlab="eigenvector 2", ylab="eigenvector 1")
```

I want to add PCA points labels based on `sample.id` column in tab.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 'text(tab$EV2, tab$EV1, labels=tab$sample.id, pos=3)'

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `geom_label_repel()` or `geom_text_repel()` from `ggrepel`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

tab = structure(list(sample.id = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("G1", 
"G10", "G162", "G163", "G495"), class = "factor"), EV1 = c(-0.0074331465, 
-0.0141980856, -0.0866563029, -0.0052063398, -0.0200554468), 
    EV2 = c(-0.03837111, 0.06964191, 0.02645573, 0.05399684, 
    0.02769749)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))

ggplot(tab,aes(x=EV2,y=EV1,label=sample.id))+
geom_point()+ xlab("eigenvector 2")+ 
ylab("eigenvector 1") + geom_label_repel()
```

[image]