# how to label an individual data point in PCA Plot

Tags: r

I have created a PCA plot using prcomp in R using:

```
> input <- read_excel("input.xlsx")                                                          
> data<-input[,!names(input) %in% "gene"]
> data1<-t(as.matrix(data[-1])) %*% as.matrix(data[-1]) / ncol(data)
> res.pca <- prcomp(data1, scale = TRUE)
> par(cex=0.5)
> plot(res.pca$x[,1],res.pca$x[,2], xlab="PC1", ylab = "PC2", main = "PC1 / PC2 - plot")
```

The `input.xlsx` file looks like:

```
gene    Sample1 Sample2     Sample3
A   13.932431   5.366284    6.93992
B   21.111017   0.662061    1.563687
C   26.471751   0.932416    1.673144
D   27.597507   36.591138   28.371248
E   35.324703   0           1.462438
```

I want to add label to a data point representing `Sample1` in this PCA Plot and color it red. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Line 2 of your code removes the `gene` column. Line 3 removes the `Sample1` column. Can you clarify how you plan to plot `Sample1` if you have removed it from the `prcomp` calculation?

Comment: Yes, I want to add text to this data point using input file. I labelled some data points based on x and y axis numerical limits using text function with sample names as in input file. I am not able to figure out how to label an individual datapoint. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Relevant previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983702/

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to mention one data point's name only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the `iris` data set that comes with R:

```
iris <- iris[, -5]   # Delete column with species
iris.pca <- prcomp(iris)
plot(iris.pca$x[, 1], iris.pca$x[, 2], xlab="PC1", ylab = "PC2", main = "PC1 / PC2 - plot")
text(iris.pca$x[1, 1], iris.pca$x[1, 2], "First Row", pos=4)
```

This assumes that the row to be labeled was included in the pca.
[image: PCA Plot]

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. Is there a way to color this datapoint say red? and can I add another data point in the list to highlight only two datapoints.

Comment: Try `points(iris.pca$x[1, 1], iris.pca$x[1, 2], pch=16, col="red", cex=1.25)`. The `pch=` argument sets the symbol (solid circle) and the `cex=` argument makes it a bit larger to make it more visible.

Comment: Thank you!  how can I highlight two datapoints in the same plot. Say "First Row" and "Second Row"

Comment: `text(iris.pca$x[1:2, 1], iris.pca$x[1:2, 2], c("First Row", "Second Row"), pos=4)` or just add additional `text()` lines for the second, third, etc.