# Label ggplot2 boxplot dots with sample IDs

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a simulated data `cp`

```
id       val.     tag
id1     12.60      A
id2     12.48      A
id3     12.48      B
id4     13.95      B
id5     12.60      A
id6     12.48      A
id7     11.13      A
id8     9.56       A
id9     10.32      B
id10    9.569      B
```

I used `geom_text_repel()` to label dots as recommended by a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983702/how-to-label-pca-points-based-on-sample-id-in-r)

**My code:**

`ggplot(cp, aes(x=tag, y=val,label=id)) + geom_boxplot()+ geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1)+geom_text_repel(arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")),box.padding = 1) + theme_bw()`

**Plot**

[image]

**My question:**

How to adjust parameters to plot clear `id-arrow-dot`? Here, for example, id1,id2,id5 and id6 are clustered together and it’s hard to tell which sample each arrow points to.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't they have the same values and belong to the same tag?

Comment: @Tung Yes, for overlapped dots this is a bit tricky. Even if id1 and id5 have the same value, the arrows should point to their respective points, rather than the two arrows pointing to the single point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to `jitter` the data points so that they no longer overlap so heavily. This also avoids the need to bin the y-axis and use a stacked dotplot. It's not perfect but it's useful for representing the spread of your data, which it seems like the points atop the boxplot is intended to do.

```r
cp <- readr::read_table("id       val     tag
id1     12.60      A
id2     12.48      A
id3     12.48      B
id4     13.95      B
id5     12.60      A
id6     12.48      A
id7     11.13      A
id8     9.56       A
id9     10.32      B
id10    9.569      B")

cp$tag <- factor(cp$tag)
# cp$val <- jitter(cp$val, amount = 0.5)

ggplot(cp, aes(x=tag, y=val,label=id)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_text_repel(arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")),box.padding = 1) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot with jittered data]